# bulk insert (SQL) format file last line

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I have the following csv I wish to import into my db

```
"LE";"SOURCE";"VAR_SCTARGET_NAME"
"B";"A/K";"A/K"
"A";"A/B";"A/B"
"A";"A/B";"A/C"
```

I arranged the following format file

```
10.0                            
3
1   SQLCHAR 0   0   "\";\""     1   A   ""
2   SQLCHAR 0   0   "\";\""     2   B   ""
3   SQLCHAR 0   0   "\"\r\n\""  3   AA  ""
```

which works just fine, if it weren't for the last line. The output in my db is the following

```
LE  SOURCE  VAR_SCTARGET_NAME
B   A/K       A/K
A   A/B       A/B
A   A/B       A/C"
```

How can I remove the quote on the last row? I'm working on a SQL Server platform, if it can be of any help.

Comment: Does your file end in a `\r\n`?

Comment: my file ends with a {CR}{LF} (like the other rows)